# How to handle response body when it changes based on if conditions in the program?

Tags: java

I want to manipulate response body correctly, but I have a feeling that I am doing it wrong, look at my Response class:

```
public final class Response {
    public static String body;
    private static int statusCode;

    private Response() {}

    public static APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent response() {
        assignStatusCode();
        return new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent()
                .withStatusCode(statusCode)
                .withBody(body);
    }

    private static void assignStatusCode() {
        switch (body) {
            case INVALID_REQUEST_BODY:
            case NULL_REQUEST_BODY:
                statusCode = STATUS_400;
                break;

            case INVALID_EMPLOYEE_DATA:
            case ALREADY_EMPLOYED:
            case EMPLOYEE_SAVED:
                statusCode = STATUS_200;
                break;

            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(UNKNOWN_RESPONSE_BODY);
        }
    }
}
```

Cases like INVALID_REQUEST_BODY are just Strings defined in other class. I have a program in which at the end I want to return a response with the appropriate response body and status code. The program is much bigger but I mean something like that:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        //some code

        public boolean isShiftPossible (Shift shift){
            if (!isShiftDateTimeValid(shift)) {
                Response.body = INVALID_DATE_TIME;
            } else if (isShiftAlreadyPlanned(shift)) {
                Response.body = SHIFT_EXISTS;
            } else {
                Response.body = SHIFT_SAVED;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    
        //some code

        return response();
    }
```

In addition I am getting following warning from SonarLint:

> Instance methods should not write to "static" fields
> https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2696

I know what this warning means, but I don't want to make my methods static. How to design response body management properly?

Comment: Why have you declared the `body` and `statusCode` in `Response` as `static`?

Comment: @GauthamM because I want to have free access to these static fields from different packages without instantiating this class. If they were not static, I would have to create a response class object each time and return it from each method so that other classes can see what responseBody is set.

Comment: Isn't your response class representing a response to a single request?

Comment: Yes it is, but suppose I have 20 classes and in every method of this classes I have if conditions that changes my responseBody field. How to design Response class then?

Comment: Suppose you have 3 classes, then : `class1` method calls `class2` method and `class2` method would call `class3` method. Now, class3 method would create a response object and return it back to `class2` which returns it back to `class1` after its own update. It would be similar for 20 classes as well right?

Comment: In case described by you, I would have to change my return type of methods to `Response`. For example my `isShiftPossible` method should return `Response` instead of `boolean` - I don't want to allow such a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the fields in `Response` as `static` would cause issues when handling simultaneous requests.

Suppose request1 and request2 are received at nearly the same time. request1 sets the response `body` to `SHIFT_SAVED`, and before the response for request1 is returned, request2 sets the response `body` to `INVALID_DATE_TIME`.

In such a case, response to both the requests would be `INVALID_DATE_TIME`.
So, each request **should** have a separate response.

From your comment in the question, If you have multiple classes handling a particular request, then do similar to the below pseudo-code after removing the `static` for `body` and `statusCode` in `Response`.

```
ClassOne {
    handleRequest(Request request) {
        // First method that handles the request creates the response object
        // which is then passed on to the other classes.
        Response response = new Response();
        ClassTwo two = new ClassTwo();
        two.handleRequest(request,response);
    }
}

ClassTwo {
    handleRequest(Request request, Response response) {
        ClassThree three = new ClassThree();
        boolean value = two.handleRequest(request,response);
        // do some process with value 
        // update body of response        
    }
}

ClassThree {
    boolean handleRequest(Request request, Response response) {
         response.body = some_value;
         // do the processing.. update response
         return true;
    }
}
```